# RSpec: how to test file operations and file content

Tags: ruby, file, testing, rspec, file-io

In my app, I have the following code:

```
File.open "filename", "w" do |file|
  file.write("text")
end
```

I want to test this code via RSpec. What are the best practices for doing this?

Comment: @Wayne I'm wondering how you will proceed with testunit
See [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619884/testunit-how-to-test-file-operations-and-file-content

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I would suggest using `StringIO` for this and making sure your [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) accepts a stream to write to instead of a filename. That way, different files or outputs can be used (more reusable), including the string IO (good for testing)

So in your test code (assuming your SUT instance is `sutObject` and the serializer is named `writeStuffTo`:

```
testIO = StringIO.new
sutObject.writeStuffTo testIO 
testIO.string.should == "Hello, world!"
```

String IO behaves like an open file. So if the code already can work with a File object, it will work with StringIO.

Comment: This was an excellent answer. I wish I could upvote you more than once.

Comment: Good answer, I know it was not asked but it would have been perfect if It included the partner 'read' example as well.

Comment: How to modify the code to use String.IO? It seems resulting code will be much uglier, just so testing is easier?

Comment: I've added more info to the answer on what the StringIO class does. You could combine my answer with Wayne's and mock('file') with a wrapper to a StringIO object.

Answer (score 52):

For very simple i/o, you can just mock File.  So, given:

```
def foo
  File.open "filename", "w" do |file|
    file.write("text")
  end
end
```

then:

```
describe "foo" do

  it "should create 'filename' and put 'text' in it" do
    file = mock('file')
    File.should_receive(:open).with("filename", "w").and_yield(file)
    file.should_receive(:write).with("text")
    foo
  end

end
```

However, this approach falls flat in the presence of multiple reads/writes: simple refactorings which do not change the final state of the file can cause the test to break.  In that case (and possibly in any case) you should prefer @Danny Staple's answer.

Answer (score 22):

This is how to mock File (with rspec 3.4), so you could write to a buffer and check its content later:

```
it 'How to mock File.open for write with rspec 3.4' do
  @buffer = StringIO.new()
  @filename = "somefile.txt"
  @content = "the content fo the file"
  allow(File).to receive(:open).with(@filename,'w').and_yield( @buffer )

  # call the function that writes to the file
  File.open(@filename, 'w') {|f| f.write(@content)}

  # reading the buffer and checking its content.
  expect(@buffer.string).to eq(@content)
end
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use [fakefs](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs).

It stubs filesystem and creates files in memory

You check with

```
File.exists? "filename"
```

if file was created.

You can also just read it with

```
File.open
```

and run expectation on its contents.

Comment: Note that FakeFS fails with Rspec (both Rspec 2 and Rspec 3) - https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs/issues/215

Answer (score 3):

For someone like me who need to modify multiple files in multiple directories (e.g. generator for Rails), I use temp folder.

```
Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
  Dir.chdir(dir) do
    # Generate a clean Rails folder
    Rails::Generators::AppGenerator.start ['foo', '--skip-bundle']
    File.open(File.join(dir, 'foo.txt'), 'w') {|f| f.write("write your stuff here") }
    expect(File.exist?(File.join(dir, 'foo.txt'))).to eq(true)
  end
end
```