# Test::Unit how to test file operations and file content

Tags: ruby, file, mocking, testunit

I'm looking for a way to test methods that use File class with test_unit.
It's really the same thing that [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070422/rspec-how-to-test-file-operations-and-file-content) with Rspec but how to make it work with test_unit.

```
def foo
  File.open "filename", "w" do |file|
    file.write("text")
  end
end
```

What will the test be :

```
require 'test/unit'

def test_foo
...
end
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing the RSpec question landed on: have `foo` accept any `IO` object and use a `StringIO` in tests.

```
def foo(io)
  io.write("text")
end
```

Then

```
require "test/unit"

def test_foo
  testIO = StringIO.new
  foo testIO 
  assert_equal(testIO.string, "text")
end
```