# What is `StringIO` in the context of RSpec testing (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stringio

What is `StringIO` in Ruby on Rails?

I'm trying to understand another SO answer that references `StringIO`, but its over my head.

> I would suggest using StringIO for this and making sure your SUT
>   accepts a stream to write to instead of a filename.

```
testIO = StringIO.new
sutObject.writeStuffTo testIO 
testIO.string.should == "Hello, world!"
```

Source: [Rspec: how to test file operations and file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070422/rspec-how-to-test-file-operations-and-file-content)

**Ruby-doc.org**

> Pseudo I/O on String object.

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html)

**Robots.thoughtbot**

> This is common in tests where we might inject a StringIO instead of
>   reading an actual file from disk.

Source: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/io-in-ruby#stringio

**My case:**

```
File.open("data.dat", "wb") {|f| f.write(snapshot)}
```

In my application I want to test the above, but I'm still confused how `StringIO` applies to implementing an RSpec test.

Could anyone with some experience in `StringIO` give some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StringIO is a string-based replacement for an IO object. It acts same as a file, but it's kept in memory as a String.

In your case I don't think it's really applicable. At least not with your current code. That's because you have `File.open` call that creates an IO object and immediately does something with it.

If for example you had something like this:

```
def write_data(f)
  f.write(snapshot)
end

# your code would be
f = File.open("data.dat", "wb")
write_data(f)

# test would be
testIO = StringIO.new
write_data(testIO)
testIO.string.should == "Hello, world!"
```